# How can I prevent extra characters at the end of my string in Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

### Background

I'm working on a Javascript application where users have to use a specific email domain to sign up (Either `@a.com` or `@b.com`. Anything else gets rejected).

I've created a regex string that makes sure the user doesn't do `@a.com` with nothing in front of it and limits users to only `@a.com` and `@b.com`. The last step is to make sure the user doesn't add extra characters to the end of `@a.com` by doing something like `@a.com.gmail.com`

This is the regex I currently have: 
`\b[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*@(a.com|b.com)`

### Question

What can I use at the end to prevent anything from being added after `a.com` or `b.com`? I'm very novice at regex and have no idea where to start.

Comment: Add `$` to the regex's end. `$` means your match should be at the strings' end

Comment: When I do that in a regex editor online, I don't get any matches at all. Do I need to add a \ or anything?

Comment: It works for me: [`\b[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*@[ab]\.com$`](https://regex101.com/r/tS4lX9/1)

Comment: Ahh. I didn't have the `m` flag on it. Works perfectly. If you put it in an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!!

Comment: The `(m)ultiline` flag threats each line as a separate string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your problem add `$` to the regex's end. `$` means your match should be at the strings' end.

Also you can reduce `(a.com|b.com)` to `[ab]\.com`. *Look I've also escaped the dot*

The character class `[ab]` means one of its characters should be matched.

Check this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS4lX9/1).

As stated in the comments, be sure to use the `(m)ultiline` flag, this way the regex engine will threat each line as a separate string.